# GitHub: Apply master commits to another branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-commit

The repository related to this question is located [here](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline).

I created a new branch called `apt-offline-python3-dev` from the master branch with the
GitHub web interface.

What I want to do is take over the commits from the master branch from commit [774](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline/commit/9f2f667d134330c0de8700258ab98cae0ac89438)-[784](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline/commit/27fc6432f6b348c0ffd0949eaa72bb5b49986743), and therefore make them belong to the `apt-offline-python3-dev` branch, instead of belonging to the `master` branch.

Because, when you look at the [latest](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline/commit/27fc6432f6b348c0ffd0949eaa72bb5b49986743) commit for example it clearly says **master** instead of **apt-offline-python3-dev**, which is logical because I sent all those commits to the master branch,
before restructuring the repository.

I then want to reset the master branch back to its original state, which means back to commit [9f2f667d13](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline/commit/9f2f667d134330c0de8700258ab98cae0ac89438) as seen on [this](https://github.com/netcyphe/apt-offline/commits/apt-offline-python3-dev) page at Jun 16, 2013.

Now, I know about `git cherry-pick` and `git merge`, but don't really know if this is possible at all.

**Update:**
+1 for Matt's answer leading me in the right direction. Unfortunately, there are still persisting problems.
Here's what happens, when I issue the commands in the order Matt suggests:

```
git checkout apt-offline-python3-dev
Branch apt-offline-python3-dev set up to track remote branch apt-offline-python3-dev from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'apt-offline-python3-dev'

git cherry-pick 9f2f667d134330c0de8700258ab98cae0ac89438
error: could not apply 9f2f667... half implementation of lock, please verify
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Because it already fails here, there is no need to invoke the `git revert` command.

Now, if one flips the order and replaces `git revert` with `git reset --hard`, it actually works:

```
git reset --hard 9f2f667d134330c0de8700258ab98cae0ac89438
HEAD is now at 9f2f667 half implementation of lock, please verify

git cherry-pick ba8662eb8e01cebc969126650baa22776a27430d
[apt-offline-python3-dev 78c9aa5] Another initial test commit
 Author: codingaround <codingaround@outlook.com>
 24 files changed, 1438 insertions(+), 1328 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 IMPORTANT_README.md
 rewrite apt_offline_core/AptOfflineMagicLib.py (85%)
```

A `git log` reveals, that the hash is a new one:

```
git log
commit 78c9aa5b732d559f141c9bf77c801c1644710432
Author: codingaround <codingaround@outlook.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 30 20:11:55 2013 +0200

    Another initial test commit
```

The question that now remains is: How do I keep the commit hashes or is that not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git cherry-pick` to apply the changes from master to the desired branch:

```
git checkout apt-offline-python3-dev
git cherry-pick <sha1>
git cherry-pick <sha1>
...
```

Then, in a separate step, revert the changes to master:

```
git checkout master
git revert <sha1>
git revert <sha1>
...
```

(git revert will add new commits undoing the changes made)